# making Google Test Framework output user defined types

Tags: c++, unit-testing, namespaces, operator-overloading

I would like to output my types in the mentioned testing framework.  [Google clearly states](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Teaching_Google_Test_How_to_Print_Your_Values) that it's possible.

`As mentioned earlier, the printer is extensible. That means you can teach it to do a better job at printing your particular type than to dump the bytes. To do that, define << for your type:`

```
namespace foo {

class Bar { ... };

// It's important that PrintTo() is defined in the SAME
// namespace that defines Bar.  C++'s look-up rules rely on that.
void PrintTo(const Bar& bar, ::std::ostream* os) {
     *os << bar.DebugString();  // whatever needed to print bar to os
}

}  // namespace foo
```

I seem to have done this. But when trying to compile I'm getting the following:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘* os << val’ /usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:108: note: candidates are:
```

It is followed by long list of proposals with my overloaded `operator<<` at the end:

```
std::ostream& Navmii::ProgrammingTest::operator<<(std::ostream&, Navmii::ProgrammingTest::AsciiString&)
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have defined `operator<<` for non-const `AsciiString` objects. Whatever Google is trying to print is probably const. Pass the second parameter as a const reference instead since you shouldn't be modifying the value you print:

```
std::ostream& Navmii::ProgrammingTest::operator<<(
  std::ostream&,
  Navmii::ProgrammingTest::AsciiString const&);
```

That more closely matches the code from the linked documentation. That part is omitted from the quotation in the question, though.

The question quotes the `PrintTo` example. That code is fine, but I don't think that's what you've really done in your own code. As the documentation says, you can use `PrintTo` if you don't want to provide `operator<<`, or if the `operator<<` for your class is inappropriate for the purposes of debug output during unit tests.

Comment: Thank you. Messages from compiler can be very confusing, although this probably not the worst one.

Comment: True. When there's only one function with a certain name, the compiler can be helpful by telling you which parameters didn't match what was expected. But when more than one function matches the requested name (`operator<<`, in this case), the error message would be even more unwieldy if it tried to explain why every single function failed to satisfy the given usage. C++ has no concept of the "closest non-match"; if it did, it might have figured out that your non-const function was "pretty close," and then just shown how that single function differed from the attempted usage in your code.